Getting categories in Flutter News Toolkit
While trying to retrieve categories from the categories endpoint, I have ran into this error: _TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast)
This error is thrown by the return in the extension from the myprojectname_api_client.dart:
 Future<CategoriesResponse> getCategories() async {
    final uri = Uri.parse('$_baseUrl/categories');
    final response = await _httpClient.get(
      uri,
      headers: await _getRequestHeaders(),
    );
    final body = response.json();

    if (response.statusCode != HttpStatus.ok) {
      throw BernardinaiApiRequestFailure(
        body: body,
        statusCode: response.statusCode,
      );
    }

    return CategoriesResponse.fromJson(body);
  }

//------------

extension on http.Response {
  Map<String, dynamic> json() {
    try {
      final decodedBody = utf8.decode(bodyBytes);
      log("MyLog $body");
      return jsonDecode(decodedBody) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    } catch (error, stackTrace) {
      Error.throwWithStackTrace(
        BernardinaiApiMalformedResponse(error: error),
        stackTrace,
      );
    }
  }
}

The log shows that the decodeBody contains the full JSON from the categories endpoints.
The getCategories method in my custom class that implements NewsDataSource class looks like this:
Future<List<Category>> getCategories() async {
  final uri = Uri.parse('https://www.mynewsurl.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories');
  final categoriesResponse = await http.get(uri);

  if (categoriesResponse.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok) {
    // Parse the response body into a Map
    final Map<String, dynamic> categoriesData = jsonDecode(categoriesResponse.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    
    // Access the 'categories' list from the map
    final List<dynamic> categoriesList = categoriesData['categories'] as List<dynamic>;
    log("MyLog categoriesList: $categoriesList");
    
    // Extract category names and return them as a list of Category enums
    final List<Category> categories = categoriesList.map((dynamic categoryData) {
      final String categoryName = categoryData as String; // Explicitly cast to String
      log("MyLog categoryName: $categoryName");

      return Category.fromString(categoryName); // Use fromString to get the enum
    }).toList();
    
    log("MyLog categories to return: $categories");

    return categories; // Returns list of category names
  } else {
    // Handle error cases by throwing a custom exception
    throw BernardinaiApiRequestFailure(
      statusCode: categoriesResponse.statusCode,
      body: jsonDecode(categoriesResponse.body) as Map<String, dynamic>,
    );
  }
}

///------

class CategoriesInfo {
  const CategoriesInfo(this.slug);

  final String slug;

  CategoriesInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : slug = _isKebabCase(json['slug'] as String)
            ? _convertToCamelCase(json['slug'] as String)
            : json['slug'] as String;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
      log("mano as veikiu");
    return {
      'slug': slug,
    };
  }

  static bool _isKebabCase(String input) {
    log("MyLog checking what case is used");
    return input.contains('-');
  }

  static String _convertToCamelCase(String input) {
    log("MANO slugas: $input");
    List<String> parts = input.split('-');
    if (parts.length == 1) return input;

    String camelCase = parts[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < parts.length; i++) {
      camelCase += parts[i][0].toUpperCase() + parts[i].substring(1);
    }

    return camelCase;
  }
}

I tried to change the extension type to List, but then all the other methods are throwing the same error, so now I am wondering if the Future<List<Category>> getCategories()  should not be a list but a map? But it was defined like that in the template, so maybe it's one of the bugs? Or perhaps I am not seeing something? I am completely lost and the documentation is of no help to me, so any help will be appreciated.

It would be clearer if you include the API response and models

Thanks for the tip! After searching for what was causing the problem, I found that it was caused not by the code itself, but by the logic I was trying to implement, so after taking care of it, now everything is working.

After analysing my code, I found that the problem was the logic I was trying to implement - the link inside the Future<CategoriesResponse> getCategories() should have been the link to the server that formats data to blocks that the app is expecting, and not to the JSON data source.
